# How to understand the quesion below?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> To what is the modern cult of beauty due? Why is it not exclusively a
>   function (in the mathematical sense) of wealth? Explain your opinion
>   with examples.

I can not understand first two sentences above. What is the meaning of the first sentence? Does it mean that what the modern cult of beauty really is? In my opinion, the word ***due*** here means ***exactly***, is that right?

As for the second sentence, I think it means the modern cult of beauty is not only produced by wealth. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2):

Due means "cause" in this case. Rewording: What is the cause of the modern cult of beauty? Answer: The modern cult of beauty is due to...

Your understanding of the second sentence is correct. The question asks "Why is more than wealth responsible?"

Comment: so the statement is that the modern cult of beauty is due to something. And when it becomes a question, and the to was moved to the beginning of the question. Is that right? It should be what is the modern cult of beauty due to?

Comment: "What is the modern cult of beauty due to?" has the exact same meaning, yes; however, some people prefer not to end a sentence with a preposition (to). Both versions would be equally well understood. :)

Comment: I would prefer "What is the modern cult of beauty due to?" because the usual reply uses the same form "Due to...".